# Германия и немцы

Tags: этимология

Почему, если страна называется Германия, её жители — не германцы, а немцы?

Comment: Почти вся северная и западная Европа говорит на языках, принадлежащих германской группе. Скорее всего, все иностранцы раньше действительно были для славян непонятными т.е. немыми. Дело в том, что ни один немец не называет себя германцем (разве что в общем смысле, как русский называет себя славянином). Немцы в Германии называют себя Дойче (deutsche), а страну дойчланд. Кстати, австрийцы и швейцарцы называют себя тоже Дойче. О происхождении этого слова пока ничего внятного не нашла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "немцы" как обозначение иностранцев, живущих в России (а это большей частью были выходцы из Германии) появилось при Петре I. Происходит оно от слова "немой", то есть, в данном случае, не говорящий и не понимающий по-русски.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что сами немцы являются и германцами.

Comment: Слово немьць - древнерусское, как оно могло появиться при Петре?

Answer (score 0):

А *Германия*, очевидно, имеет корень *яр/гер/хер/iero*.

*Германы* - "мужественные мужи".
Но мы-то, русские, их круче, поэтому и прозвали их *немцами*.;)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут описано :
http://vopros.es/10/g6/88-pochemu-strana-germaniya-a-narod-nemcy.html

Comment: Alexab, на ресурсе не приветствуется ответ в виде одной ссылки. Напишите основную мысль, ссылкой можно её подтверлить.

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос "почему" ответа, естественно дать невозможно. Так сложилось волею истории языка. Германцами называли все германские племена, расселившиеся по всей Европе (собственно предков современных немцев среди них было не так немного), когда образовалась Германия для её жителей не нашлось "вакантного" слова, пригодилось это древнеславянское "немец".

Насчет версии "немец" - от немой. Судя по всему, все почти "с точностью до наоборот".

*немъ* - древнерусское прилагательное, (образовано, возможно, от "не+им", где им - тот же морф, что и иметь). И вот так "немами", "немцами" с незапамятных величали всех иностранцев, "не имеющих" по мысли древних славян земли, имущества и т.д. Вряд ли в те времена это могло быть связано с "неимением языка", ибо смешение народов тогда было обычным делом, сами славяне появились на территории, где соседствовали многочисленные народы самых разных языковых семей. Скорее уж сами славяне были там "немыми".
Только много позже, параллельно с давно существующим "немец", могло появиться это "немой" в значении "не говорящий". Обратите внимание, что в версии немец<немой есть еще логическая неувязочка. Куда логичнее было бы назвать такого человека "глухим", как это и сейчас делается ("Ты глухой, что ли?").

Comment: *собственно предков современных немцев среди них было не так немного* — а кем были в основном предки современных немцев? Балто-славяне? Или условные "кельты"?

Comment: *а кем были в основном предки современных немцев?* - это несколько другой вопрос. Немцы вобрали в себя, помимо германцев, пруссов (балтийцев), полабских славян и многие другие, более мелкие племена. Но я говорил о том, что далеко не все германские племена стали немцами. Надеюсь, не надо доказывать, что англы, саксы, бритты, франки, .норманы (французские и скандинавские), даны, шведы и многие прочие - это все племена германские.